# Make an array expand to the left of the cell with the formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrays

Is there a way (or workaround) to make an array expand to the left of the cell with the formula? (Above the formula would also work)

Here's a spreadsheet with more detail on what I'm looking for. (I'm using ARRAYFORMULA here, but would be open to a workaround using any function)

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DDoWPJWTr5O9vlhaqKEyKXIGlKVJXbw03Z28ZN-MMe8/

Comment: The naive answer to your question is no, you can't expand arrays leftwards/above the formula cell, but your question feels like a bit of an XY problem - can you elaborate further on what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: See [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676)

Comment: This is for an assignment that I will be giving my students. I would like to display a column of values only if a checkbox is checked. I will be the one checking the box - only for students with specific accommodations. It will make the questions easier, so I don't want the other students to stumble across the checkbox. My normal solution is to stick hidden stuff way over in column Z or someplace where the students wont normally go, but I need these students with accommodations to be able to see it without scrolling.

Comment: I thought about placing the formula in a column, then hiding this column, and letting the array expand into the next column, but that seems too easy for the students to figure out. (But maybe I'm giving them too much credit here...) :)

Comment: I can think of a few hacky approaches which might achieve something akin to what you want to do, but I wonder if using Google Forms might be more appropriate here - you could have two different forms for each category of student with/without the additional values.

Comment: Unfortunately, Forms won't work for my situation. The particular style of assignment I'm needing this for is Parson's Problems (Where students unscramble lines of computer programming code) Rearranging the rows in a spreadsheet works really well.

Comment: I'm interested to hear your hacky approaches.

Answer (score 0):

A formula will always put something in the cell where the formula is. An array formula may also fill cells down and to the right of the formula cell, but not to the left or up.

In other words, the formula will have to go in cell `A1` or `A2`. You can specify a custom header text directly in an array formula cell like this:

```
={ 
  "text that goes to the header cell A1"; 
  C2:C5 
}
```

For completeness, I should mention that spreadsheets that use a LTR writing system have the left and right directions reversed, but that does not change the overarching principle.